# Why is deque faster than queue?

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, deque

I have the following working codes (g++ 8.2 , the C++17 standard.)

```
    queue<TreeNode*> q{};

    q.push(root);
    q.push(nullptr);
    int sum = root -> val;
    while (!q.empty()) {
        TreeNode *n = q.front();
        q.pop();

        if (n != nullptr) {
            sum += n->val;
            if (n-> left != nullptr) q.push(n->left);
            if (n-> right != nullptr) q.push(n->right);   
        } else {
            if (q.empty()) break;
            q.push(nullptr);
            sum = 0;
        }

    }
    return sum;
```

Then I replaced `queue<TreeNode*>` with `deque<TreeNode*>`. It turned out the speed improved at least 20%. Why is `deque<TreeNode*>` so much faster than `queue<TreeNode*>`?

Comment: Would be helpful if you specify what compiler you used for this finding

Comment: Are you testing a unoptimized debug build or an optimized release build? What are your compiler flags/options?

Comment: Can you supply the minimum code used to make the timings and the compiler settings used to compile the code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [cppreference.com: std::queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::deque<T>
> class queue;
```

> `Container` - The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements.

So `std::queue` - by default - uses `std::deque`  as its internal container, due to that it can only be at best as fast as `std::deque` (or the underlying container in general), and because being a wrapper it is - depending on the optimization the compiler can do - slower. So if you correctly measure a 20% slowdown, then you measure how good the compiler is in optimizing the wrapper code away at the given optimization level.

As `std::queue` exists to guarantee a FIFO usage, by only exposing these functions, I doubt - but I can't test it right now - that the slow down is that drastically with optimizations turned on. If it is I would consider that as a bug/defect of the capabilities of the compiler or library implementation.